# Show user posts in post list

Tags: python, django

The following method returns a queryset of posts of users that i follow.

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # returns the users that i follow
    following_users = self.request.user.profile.get_following() 

    #gets posts of following users
    qs = Tweet.objects.filter(user__in=following_users).order_by("-timestamp") 

    return qs
```

I want to add my own posts too in this query set. How to add my own user in this queryset?
Something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # returns the users that i follow
    following_users = self.request.user.profile.get_following() 

    following_users.append(self.request.user) # This is not working

    #gets posts of following users
    qs = Tweet.objects.filter(user__in=following_users).order_by("-timestamp") 

    return qs
```

Something like this> How should i do that?

Im begginer plz help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because, likely `get_following()` returns a `QuerySet`, not a list, and you can not append to a `Queryset`.

Likely it is easier to just implement with disjunctive condition:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    following_users = self.request.user.profile.get_following()
    return Tweet.objects.filter(
        Q(user__in=following_users) |
        Q(user=self.request.user)
     ).order_by('-timestamp')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), so you look for posts from users that you follow OR from yourself

```
from django.db.models import Q


def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # returns the users that i follow
    following_users = self.request.user.profile.get_following() 

    #gets posts of following users
    qs = Tweet.objects.filter(Q(user__in=following_users) | Q(user=self.request.user)).order_by("-timestamp") 

    return qs
```